# Find and replace starting from the end

Tags: php, regex, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preg Replace - replace second occurance of a match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687334/preg-replace-replace-second-occurance-of-a-match)

I have a string that includes the word `rules` twice. I need to find and replace the 2nd word. Tried fooling around with `str_replace()` but couldn't get anything, the 4th parameter wasn't what I expected.

Here is an example string:

```
http://localhost/proj1/modstart/admin/index.php?i=rules&sid=397ab1f6b8eb8a17787438a7e2e60ea3&mode=rules
```

After my replace it should look like this:

```
http://localhost/proj1/modstart/admin/index.php?i=rules&sid=397ab1f6b8eb8a17787438a7e2e60ea3&mode=manage
```

I read that `preg_replace()` could help, but I don't know how to write patterns.

Ideas?

P.S: Don't suggest splitting the string into two variables, that wouldn't serve my needs.

Comment: Though you could also just write a simple regex matching the word twice, keeping the first part, filler and remainder. * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: It's not a dupe. My question differs from the one you linked, not that much but it does.

Comment: is the second keyword always going to be the end of string??

Comment: Nope, it wont. :\ I'd be using substr_replace() in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a very good idea to learn about regular expressions. In PHP, you can accomplish your find/replace like this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(rules.*?)rules/','$1manage',$str,1);
```

It basically finds "rules" once, then anything, then rules a second time, then puts it all back before the second match and replaces the word.

Answer (score 0):

To not use a regular expression, and also to not store anything into a second variable, you could use `str_replace()` with a little magic from `strpos()`:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($str, 'rules') + 5) . str_replace('rules', 'whatever', substr($string, strpos($string, 'rules') + 5));
```

This will take the full string up-to the end of the first instance of `rules` and then do the string-replacement on the second-part of the string which will contain any other instance of the word.

The same thing, but a little more cleaner (yes, by using a second variable):

```
$pos = strpos($string, 'rules') + 5;
$string = substr($string, 0, $pos) . str_replace('rules', 'whatever', substr($string, $pos));
```

If the word to find+replace is dynamic or you want to use a different word on different pages, you could make *that* a variable, like this:

```
$findMe = 'rules';
$replaceWith = 'whatever';
$pos = strpos($string, $findMe) + strlen($findMe);
$string = substr($string, 0, $pos) . str_replace($findMe, $replaceWith, substr($string, $pos));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex >>

```
$new = preg_replace('/\brules\b(?!.*\brules\b)/', 'manage', $old);
```

It is a good idea to use word boundaries `\b`, so it will not match some larger strings that contain **"rules"**, such as **"preudorules"**.

Negative lookahead `(?!.*\brules\b)` ensures there is no other word **"rules"** behind, so the one you are replacing is the last one.