# PHP Find and replace multiple similar entries

Tags: php, search, replace

I've got a text file which contains about 60 lines. Within in that are 2 lines:

```
DeviceIP 10.0.0.1
DeviceIP 10.2.36.4
```

I have a PHP form which has `$device1` & `$device2`

How do I find and replace in the file, replacing the first DeviceIP with $device1 and the second with $device2 ?

Obviously the IP Addresses will change so I can't search on those. I know how to do it for one match, but not multiple.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687334/preg-replace-replace-second-occurance-of-a-match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687334/preg-replace-replace-second-occurance-of-a-match)

Comment: Do you want to replace IP address (10.0.0.1) with your $device1 value??

Comment: yes thats what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
           $arr=array('10.0.0.10','10.22.32.12');
            $handle = fopen("test.txt", "r");
            $str="";
            if ($handle) {
                $count=0;
                while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
                    if(preg_match("/DeviceIP/", $buffer)){
                        $str.= "DeviceIP ".$arr[$count];
                        $str.="\n";
                    }
                    $count++;
                }
                if (!feof($handle)) {
                    echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
            file_put_contents('test',$str);
```

It will replace string occurrence with array value.
and this is reading line by line and replace match, I think it is good.

Answer (score 0):

Replace only the first occurrence:

```
$str = file_get_contents('yourtextfile.txt');

$str = str_replace("DeviceIP", $device1, $str, 1); // Replace only first occurrence

$str = str_replace("DeviceIP", $device2, $str, 1); // Replace second occurrence

file_put_contents('yourtextfile', $str);
```

Comment: IMHO this is not excatly what OP asked for as he want to change the IP not the string *DeviceIP*, so the str_replace won't work (it smells regex here, but you can't change nth occurrence with regex only)

Comment: @Chizzle it's the IP Address I want to change not DeviceIP. Any way to so that ?

Comment: Assuming the file's IP addresses are seperated by line breaks, you can use file(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php Check out this answer about looping through line by line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991843/replace-line-in-text-file-using-php

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$test = file('test');
$result = ''; $count ='1';
foreach($test as $v) {
    if (substr($v,0,8) == 'DeviceIP' && $count =='1') {
        $result .= "DeviceIP $device1\n"; $count++;
    } elseif (substr($v,0,8) == 'DeviceIP' && $count =='2') {
        $result .= "DeviceIP $device2\n";
    } else {
        $result .= $v;
    }
}
file_put_contents('test', $result);
```

But is it the best way to do this ?

Comment: Here every time you are checking sub string and count. It is better to read file line by line and replace what you need